# Errno 24: Too many open files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Python program which makes use of the following possibilities.

- Makes use of Requests
- Makes use of mariadb to connect to MariaDB database
- Makes use of Python telegram bot
- Makes use of Selenium
- Makes use of a file

So, after getting this error for the first time,I reviewed my code and all requests has in headers `Connection:"close"`. Every single connection is closed after being used. The driver used in selenium is closed afterwards and the files are open with the `with` and hence, close after read or write.

Still, after a day or so of running, the program keeps hanging because of this error. Do I need to close python telegram bot as well? What can it be? How do I fix it?

I don't append the code because it is several thousand of lines and all of the above are used at different parts.

Comment: Are you using the "file" with a `with` as well?

Comment: Yes, I read it within the with, and when I have to write to it as well.

Comment: Given the complexity of your code (multiple pieces), it would be helpful to see your code.